# can't pass value pressed the button in swift

Tags: swift, button, printing

in swift I can't pass the value that is passed by pressing the button and I have to print it. I use an if and it always prints the first value.

```
if zeroPctButton.titleLabel!.text! == "0%" {
                print("0.0")
        } else if tenPctButton.titleLabel!.text! == "10%" {
                    print("0.1")
                }else {
                    print("0.2")
                }
```

Comment: And if you print `zeroPctButton.titleLabel!.text!` & `tenPctButton.titleLabel!.text!` at start, what's the output?

Comment: but each button as written in code must give a different answer.  the if does not work and always takes the first value "0.0".

Comment: Where does that if statement in your question appear? In the IBAction method that is triggered by your button? And what do you mean “the value that is passed by pressing the button”? A value is not passed by pressing a button. An IBAction method gets triggered, and that method may get passed the target (The button that was tapped).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the liguca is found within a function.  if I used le print individually, it writes correctly.  I don't understand why if I use the if on the label of a button it doesn't return the data.  can you tell me where am I wrong?. Thank you

Comment: is found in the function of the uibotton

Comment: fir way to help me?  thank you.

Comment: I resolved. From iOS 13 it’s ok